# How do I skip some lines of code based on whether I have selected a cell in Row3 or not?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a spreadsheet where the user selects any cell and then runs this macro. If the cell is not in Row 3 then select the entire row that that cell is in, cut and insert that row in Row 3.  (this part works fine)  If the selected cell is in Row 3 then I want to skip the cut and insert part of the code.    This seems like it should be simple to do but I get the error: End if without block if, when I run this macro.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
Dim Row As String

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

strRow = Selection


If Selection = Rows("3:3") Then GoTo SkipToHere
End If

Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-84
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A3").Select



SkipToHere:
```

Comment: Generally any form of `Selecting` in vba usually is bad, but for your current situation it _may be slightly okay_ with emphasis on slightly.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GoTo in this context is probably not the best way to go about this. Instead I would just encase your first part in an If:

```
Dim strRow As String

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

strRow = Selection

If Selection.Row <> 3 Then

    Selection.Cut
    Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A3").Select

End If
```

You should also as a matter of principle avoid .Select where you do not need it.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, you can write `IF` statements in multiple ways: 1. All on one line, or 2. With an `Else` component, or 3. using `ElseIf` ... etc.

When you write an `IF` statement like this:

`If A=True Then B`

with no `Else` component, then VBA does not require an `End IF` statement. It is needed when you use `IF` like this:

```
IF A=True Then
  Do this
Else
  Do Something else
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Row As String

If Activecell.Row = 3 Then GoTo SkipToHere
End If

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-84
Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A3").Select



SkipToHere:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Horsten()
```

'   Do the selection and the third row have nothing in commen?

```
If Intersect(Selection, Rows(3)) Is Nothing Then
```

'       Then cut and paste (but without changing the selection)

```
    Selection.EntireRow.Cut
    Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

'       Then adjust the positioning if you like

```
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=84
    Cells(3, 1).Select
End If

End Sub
```